# Editor does not contain main type in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, editor, types, program-entry-point

I got this message when running my project in Eclipse, and I am sure that  I have a main in my project. I tried cleaning, closing and re-opening it, but nothing works. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

The *currently opened* source code doesn't have a `public static void main(String[] args)` method. Ensure that you're opening and focusing the right source code which contains the method and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

It could be many things.

Try to clean your workspace first and check your configuration used to start your project.

---

**Resources :**

- [JavaRanch - active editor does not contain a main type](http://www.coderanch.com/t/419415/vc/eclipse-active-editor-does-not)

**On the same topic :**

- [Editor does not contain a main type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113729/editor-does-not-contain-a-main-type)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can get this error if your .java file is misplaced outside the src folder..

Try to verify that you .java file is under src folder.