# Launch Error: Editor does not contain a main type

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I had just found one of my old projects I made with java and when I imported it I tried to run it but it said!

Launch Error: Editor does not contain a main type.

Here is my code:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;


public class Interface {

    protected Shell shell;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Interface window = new Interface();
            window.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open the window.
     */
    public void open() {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        createContents();
        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the window.
     */
    protected void createContents() {
        shell = new Shell();
        shell.setSize(450, 300);
        shell.setText("SWT Application");

    }

}
```

Comment: The class you show is called `Interface` but Eclipse is complaining about a class called `Editor`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Editor does not contain a main type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113729/editor-does-not-contain-a-main-type)