# Does not contain main type

Tags: java

```
public class teh2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int MAXKOKO=10;
        int [] taulukko = new int[MAXKOKO];

        System.out.println("Anna kymmenen(10) lukua: ");
        int luku0 = sc.nextInt();
        int luku1 = sc.nextInt();
        int luku2 = sc.nextInt();
        int luku3 = sc.nextInt();
        int luku4 = sc.nextInt();
        int luku5 = sc.nextInt();
        int luku6 = sc.nextInt();
        int luku7 = sc.nextInt();
        int luku8 = sc.nextInt();
        int luku9 = sc.nextInt();

        taulukko[0] = luku0;
        taulukko[1] = luku1;
        taulukko[2] = luku2;
        taulukko[3] = luku3;
        taulukko[4] = luku4;
        taulukko[5] = luku5;
        taulukko[6] = luku6;
        taulukko[7] = luku7;
        taulukko[8] = luku8;
        taulukko[9] = luku9;

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Taulukko sisהltהה luvut:");
        for(int i=0; i<MAXKOKO; i++) {
            System.out.println(taulukko[i]);
    }
}
```

Doesn't work. Says it doesn't contain main type. How can I solve this?

Comment: What's the file name? It should be `teh2.java`.

Comment: "How much freakin stuff do I need to write on this in ordet o make a post." More freakin stuff than this. Just dumping code does not make a question. We are no debugging service.

Comment: _Doesn't work_ is **really** vague. How are you compiling it? How are you running it?

Comment: Edit your code :Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: It DOES NOT say *"doesn't contain main type"*.  If you want people to help you, you need to be ACCURATE in your questions.

Comment: "Editor does not contain a main type"

Comment: Probably problem not in your code after declaring Scanner sc; . I think your way of compilation is wrong

Comment: Are you compiling your code online ?

Comment: How do I do it correctly then?

Comment: What is saying this?  What IDE are you using?

Comment: Eclipse, "editor does not contain a main type"

Comment: I think this is an Eclipse bug.  See this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113729/editor-does-not-contain-a-main-type.  Read the answers, and try the things that they suggest.

Comment: Someone? Would rly appriciate.

Comment: Yeah found the answer for my question from Eclipse thread. Thank you Stephen C!

Answer (score 0):

[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113729/editor-does-not-contain-a-main-type) :In Eclipse, make sure you add your source folder in the project properties -> java build path -> source. Otherwise, the `main()` mathod may not be included in your project.

Or probably It helps if you clean your workspace and rebuild your Project.