# Eclipse not allowing me to compile

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

In Eclipse, when I try to run this code, it gives me an error message: "Editor does not contain a main type":

```
public class GalToLit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double gallons, liters;

        gallons = 10; //start with 10 gallons

        liters = gallons * 3.7854; //convert to liters

        System.out.println(gallons + " gallons is " + liters + " liters.");
    }

}
```

Comment: Try cleaning & rebuilding

Comment: did you try saving and see if the error disappeared?

Comment: I think your question is already answered over here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113729/editor-does-not-contain-a-main-type

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that your .java files are in the .src folder in eclipse. I had the same exact problem until I got it figured out.

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to help.