# Editor does not contain a main type in Katalon studio

Tags: katalon-studio

A test case is created in Katalon studio and i am trying to run with java application. 
I have received the below error..

*"Editor does not contain a main type"*

Any insights to solve this error is helpful.

Comment: Hi, did you have the problem resolved? I am researching on Katalon Studio and it would be nice if I could have the status of the product.

Comment: I have posted this question in the Katalon support form and received a super dummy answer. which is not at all useful. So myself as a more dummy user, i uninstalled and installed katalon and i didnt got the this error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113729/editor-does-not-contain-a-main-type