# "Editor does not contain a main type" error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, testing

I have a problem with eclipse/java application.

In the moment where i was ready to run my application it tells me a message that the selection does not contain main, but isn't true (see the picture)

[image]

how can i fix this mistake ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Editor does not contain a main type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113729/editor-does-not-contain-a-main-type)

Comment: How in the UI did you try to Run it?